# Detect browser's width and close aria-expanded div

Tags: jquery, html

**CODE:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(this).width() != width){
        width = $(this).width();
        if(width>=768){
            if($('search_xs').attr('aria-expanded')==='true'){
                $('search_xs').setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
                console.log('error')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

On that code, just `console.log('error')` is not working.

Where should i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to find element `<search_xs>` instead of element with `class="search_xs"`.

Use correct CSS selector for class.

```
$('.search_xs')
```

Comment: How did you know that it's a class on a certain element? It could be an ID.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `*_xs` classes are part of bootstrap, or not? If not, search_xs isn't typically id name. At least for me. The main point was that there is something missing, `.` or `#`, you're right.